# Batch file ren command access denied, but works when I type it myself

Tags: batch-file, rename, command-prompt, access-denied

I have a batch file that copies the files from where Windows stores its Lock Screen images and puts them into my own personal folder, then renames them as .jpg's so that I can use them as my active desktop backgrounds, but for some reason the "ren" command has stopped working (Access denied). However, if I open a command prompt myself and type the command, it works.

It doesn't matter if I have the final destination folder open or not, I get the same results. I have also tried running the batch file as administrator and it didn't change anything.

My code is below. For troubleshooting, I added two timeout commands just so it would stop after a couple steps to let me see what was happening. The batch file is saved here: "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop"

```
xcopy "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets" "D:\Users\Adam\Pictures\Spotlight" /y
d:
cd D:\Users\Adam\Pictures\Spotlight
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
ren *.* *.jpg
timeout /t 30 /nobreak
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `CD` requires the switch `/D` to change Root directories.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment (might be because I'm a novice). I open a cmd prompt and I start in C:\Users\Adam and it goes as follows (with my commands after the ">")
`C:\Users\Adam>d:`
`D:\>cd D:\Users\Adam\Pictures\Spotlight`
`D:\Users\Adam\Pictures\Spotlight>`
Then after that, the batch file ren command access is denied while if I just type it myself it works.

Comment: I see no reason why you cannot just use one command, `Copy /Y "%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets\*" "%UserProfile%\Pictures\Spotlight\*.jpg"`. And if your location is really in `D:`, then `Copy /Y "%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets\*" "D:\Users\Adam\Pictures\Spotlight\*.jpg"`.

Comment: Yup that worked. I changed it to `xcopy "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets" "D:\Users\Adam\Pictures\Spotlight\*.jpg" /y` but that worked as a single line - thanks! Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why you cannot just do this with a single command.

This one uses the Standard location for the users profile directory as the destination:

```batch-file
Copy /Y "%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets\*" "%UserProfile%\Pictures\Spotlight\*.jpg"
```

If your location is really in the `D:` drive then:

```batch-file
Copy /Y "%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets\*" "D:\Users\Adam\Pictures\Spotlight\*.jpg"
```

I both examples I have used the built-in `copy` command, there is no benefit in using the deprecated `xcopy.exe` utility for this, as you are not using any of its optional features.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if I needed it to still be xcopy or not, happy it works in a single line now though! Thank you! Also still don't know why access was denied in case users care about that being answered as well (I don't plan to dwell on it)